# Rails 4 where select all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you do this in Rails

In my view if I select a user then I want to show all the categories the user is in but the problem is that this is a single table (Legacy DB) there is no relationship

I have tried to do something like this but it doesn't work

```
where('user in ?', categories)
```

I Just get `ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb16f90abf0`

The table columns are like this

- user   category
- user1  category1
- user1  category2
- user2  category2
- user2  category4

Comment: because it has a relationship? check `where('user in ?', categories).to_sql` to view query

Comment: How to you intend to retrieve this if "there is no relationship"? There must be a relationship of some kind even if it is not the standard `id` to `_id` type. Maybe username is stored in both tables?

Comment: What kind of legacy database are you using? And when you say it's a single table, do you mean that the categories and users are stored in the same table?

Comment: Hi yes the users and categories is in the same table

Comment: In that case, how are the categories stored? Are they in a separate field, as a string or array of some sort?

Comment: they are stored as string

Comment: What you really need here is an instance method on User that returns the relevant Category set. Actually, an association would be preferable, but we'd need to know what the SQL is for joining the row types.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: The post states that there's no relationship, and OP's comments state that the categories are stored as a string, so there is no need for SQL or joining rows.

Comment: @djangor: Can you give an example of what a user record looks like, and also edit your question to include it? I'm assuming the categories are a comma-separated string but I want to make sure before answering.

Comment: @Matt If there is no SQL then you can't retrieve the data from the database. In other words, there definitely is SQL, and when we know what it is, we'll be able to advise on a way of constructing an ActiveRecord expression.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I think we're talking past each other. From OP's comments, it seems that `categories` are stored as a field in the users table.

Obviously you can't retrieve data from a database without SQL. (That statement seemed very patronizing to me, by the way.) My point is that I don't think this answer is going to involve an ActiveRecord expression / SQL beyond "selecting a user", as OP put it, which they are already doing.

Comment: the categories are stored as a field in the database

Comment: @djangor: Is there another table that stores more detailed user information, with one row per user; or a table with one category per row? The data structure you just added looks to me like a join table, which itself describes a many-to-many relationship between users and catgeories.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this TABLE.all.where("USERFULLNAME IN ?", category).uniq

Comment: In django I can do this def get_categories_for_user(filter_by_dates, filter_by_user):
  categories = MODELNAME.objects.all().filter(USERFULLNAME__contains=filter_by_user).values_list('CATEGORY', flat=True.distinct()

  return categories

Comment: @djangor updated my answer!

Comment: If your table contains multiple records of the same value of User, and the same value of Category, then it's not a table of User instances or Category instances. Possibly it is a table of UserCategory. In that case, `UserCategory.where(:user => user_variable)` returns all the instances, from which `.pluck(:category)` returns the values of category for that user.

Comment: @Matt I think there's just no explanation of the structure, not of how Rails is being used. I suspect that a combination of no Rails experience and a legacy database is doing the OP no favours at all here, but it ould be pretty rare that you couldn't get close to a conventional Rails way of working by knowing the structure of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to **show all the categories** the user is in

```
@categories = User.where(id: params[:id]).pluck(:category)
```

This will return a *collection* of data which you'll be able to loop through using an [`.each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) loop or some other sort of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

```
@categories.each do |category|
   category #-> since this will be a single value, you don't need any attributes
end
```

--

What you *should* be doing is using an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

[image]

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, which will give you the ability to *associate* *many* `users` with *many* `categories`, as follows:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@categories = @user.categories
```

This will also return a *collection* of data; the difference is that the `categories` in this instance will be built from each `Category` object the `user` is associated to.

You'll be able to call them as follows:

```
@user.categories.each do |category|
   category.name
end
```

To set this up, you just need to set up the *join table* (`categories_users`):

```
$ rails g migration CreateCategoriesUsers

#db/migrate/create_categories_users_____.rb
class CreateCategoriesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :categories_users, id: false do |t|
         t.references :user
         t.references :category
      end
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks man this @categories = User.where(id: params[:id]).pluck(:category) solved the problem..thank you so much

Comment: No problem - you should accept the answer if it helped. You should also read up about associations, they'll save you massive headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [direct sql query](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) to your db.

Following is an example and your query will depend on your schema:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE user_id = #{@user.id}")
result.to_a
```

### Update

On the light of comments conversations:

**assumptions #1**:

1. Legacy DB, single table, no relations, single model -> assuming **User**
2. **User** has two strings Fields: (1) user_full_name (2) category

In that case we could do:

```
User.where(:user_full_name => @user.user_full_name).pluck(:category).flat.uniq
```

Otherwise,

**assumptions #2**:

Somehow, you have no models in this db and we are back to direct sql.

```
sql = "SELECT category FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE user_full_name = #{user_full_name}"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
result.to_a.flat.uniq
```

Comment: That would not be a very Rails solution

Comment: OP said db is one big table with all data in their! i think we are already beyond "a Rails way" kind of solution!

Comment: Your assumption #2 would be `User.find_by(:user_full_name => @some_variable).category` or  `User.where(:user_full_name => @some_variable).pluck(:category)`. No reason why the User model can't be built on a table of any arbitrary name, and ActiveRecord methods used to retrieve from it.

Comment: and take the trouble of building a User model on a legacy db table just to use ActiveRecord `find` which is by the end of the day is just the same sql select query!!

Comment: Yes, do exactly that, because this is apparently a Rails app, and that means you define the logic for retrieving data in the model layer, so you don't end up writing SQL for everything. I'm assuming here that the system needs more than one query running against it, of course.